# Angular - Failed to instantiate module myapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple Angular App, however every time i load the page in the application i am getting following error.

I have home page where I access the angular page using a menu which load the content of the page by a jQuery ajax call. When I do it this way i keep getting following error even though `myapp` is present and all required files are included.

Please note that when I access the URL of the page directly in a browser it works fine...this occurs only when I access this angular page from my home page using an ajax call.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%2…jquery%2F2.2.4%2Fjquery.min.js%3A2%3A2640)%2C%20%3Canonymous%3E%3A20%3A359)
```

`

```
 Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=myapp
    at Error (native)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:6:412)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:25:72)
    at b (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:24:115)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:24:358)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:39:374)
    at r (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:7:355)
    at g (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:39:222)
    at db (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:43:246)
    at Bc.c (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:2:2640), <anonymous>:20:359
```

`

**Contoller**
`

```
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[]);
myapp.controller('UserConfigController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('/runquery/getdata/userconfig').success(function(data){ $scope.usrConf=data; });
}]);
```

`

**Page that has angular code**

```
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/s/xxxx_static/js/thirdParty/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/s/xxxx_static/js/controllers/queryContorllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myapp">
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2>
    <div ng-controller="UserConfigController">
    <div ng-repeat="it in usrConf">
        <h1>{{it.propertyName}}</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could see that the issue is due to the angular JS file 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js

Comment: Try replacing that script tag with angular JS file with the CDN , it works fine
codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZpvBO

Comment: I just changed  replaced the angular JS file - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YWNypZ    it works fine without issue .Hope this works for you :)

Comment: I tried to use CDN link but i am seeing following error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined" and above error that i mentioned in the question

Comment: The issue is when i access the page using a jquery ajax call from my home page...when i access the page directly by hitting the url in a browser..it works fine.

Comment: Then i think issue is with this line - ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/s/xxxx_static/js/thirdParty/angular.min.js

Comment: Can you try replacing that with the CDN ...it is not able recognize the path of JS file

Comment: I see that angular.min.js is getting loaded fine...Like i said when i access the page individually (by hitting the page url directly in the browser) ..everything works. The issues is when I access this angular page by an Ajax call and load the page in to a div. It is a JSP page so link will resolved to proper url and it is loading the angular.min.js fine.

Comment: Try moving <script src="..."></script> from head to end of the body section and see if its solving the loading issue

Comment: just for testing, add the CDN to the JSP and try , Hope this will resolve the issue ..because issue is that it is not able to recognize that file